# How can I avoid variable inheritance in added subdirectory in CMake?

Tags: cmake

For my own project code, I want to enable c++17 globally, so in my project's root CMakeLists.txt, I have

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

I also need to build some thirdparty library which my code depends on, I introduced it into my project using `add_subdirectory`

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
....
add_subdirectory(thirdparty/xxx)
...
```

However, `thirdparty/xxx` is not compatible with c++17, so it gives me a compile error.

I want to make it so that `set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)` is not propagated to `thirdparty/xxx`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the subdirectory defines its own value of the variable, you don't need to do anything, because its own definition of the variable will be used in its scope. If not, then you have the option to make that be the case. But if the subdirectory is a third-party / "external" project, presumably you don't want to do that- in which case, if the variable needs to be set to something in particular, then set the variable to that value before calling `add_subdirectory`, and then restore the old value right after the call to `add_subdirectory`. Otherwise, you can call `unset` before the call to `add_subdirectory`, and then restore the value right after.

Note that regular variable references will "fallback" to cache variables of the same name if a regular variable of that name is not defined, so if you use the `unset` approach, be aware that for total coverage, you'd need to also unset any possible cache variable of the same name and then restore it afterwards ([`unset(<var> CACHE)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/unset.html#unset-normal-variable-or-cache-entry), [`set(<var> <val> CACHE)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-cache-entry)).

In terms of restoring things afterward, if you have `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)`, you can use [the `block` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/block.html) to create a new block scope where you redefine the variable or unset it and then call `add_subdirectory`, and then after the block scope is exited, the value from outside that scope is "restored". Pre-CMake 3.25, you can also achieve this by defining a function with the same body and calling it, but at that point, you don't really get any improvement over restoring the value manually.

In some contexts, you might have the option of rearranging things so that you don't even set that conflicting variable before that call to `add_subdirectory`.

---

Notes on the particular scenario / context in the question post: Especially for library targets that are meant for other projects to use, I prefer to specify language standard requirements using [`target_compile_features`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_features.html) (see also [C++ language-standard compile-features](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/CMAKE_CXX_KNOWN_FEATURES.html#high-level-meta-features-indicating-c-standard-support) for example), and leave high-level / overall / default language standard for specifying on commandline with `-D` / in a CMake preset via [`CMAKE_<LANG>_STANDARD`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD.html).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot avoid propagation of a variable into a subdirectory. But before entering the subdirectory you could set the variable to the desired value.

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
....
# Set C++ standard to 14 when process subdirectory
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
add_subdirectory(thirdparty/xxx)
# Restore C++ standard for the rest of our code.
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

You may also unset the variable when entering a specific subdirectory:

```
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
....
# Let subproject to decide which C++ standard to use
unset (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
add_subdirectory(thirdparty/xxx)
# Restore C++ standard for the rest of our code.
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
```

Comment: This inspires me, maybe I should put all of the `add_subdirectory(thirdparty/...)` at the very begining of my root CMakeLists? So that my own project related variable settings afterwards won't affect thirdparty libraries

Comment: It is up to you. If **correct functioning** of the subprojects depends on many variables, which has different values for the main project, then including these subprojects at the beginning of your `CMakeLists.txt` has a sense. Otherwise I find it better to temporary redefine several variables before inclusion of the subproject(s): that way every reader of your project will clearly understand, which variables(settings) are NOT shared with a subproject and be ready to possible incompatibilities when link targets in the main project with ones in the subproject.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to avoid the global variable `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` altogether and use [`target_compile_features`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_features.html) instead for your own targets. If this is viable depends on how much effort it is to set this *globally*, i.e. for each of your targets.

In its easiest form one would write

```
add_executable(myapp ...)
target_compile_features(myapp PRIVATE cxx_std_17)
```

This is in the spirit of [Modern CMake](https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/chapters/features/cpp11.html) as it avoids global state that is - well - global with all its drawbacks. It comes with the added benefit of being upward compatible.

Comment: global state in CMake being bad in general is news to me. did someone notable say that?

Comment: Global state is problematic in programming in general. The book I linked to links in turn to a [blog by Craig Scott](https://crascit.com/2015/03/28/enabling-cxx11-in-cmake/) where he makes a very nuanced argument when to use what. In *this question*, the global variable causes a problem so I offered a solution that does without it.

Comment: yes, for specific feature/applications there are mechanisms for non-global state because those dedicated mechanisms are better. does that blogpost say that global state is bad _in general_?

Comment: @starball after a night's sleep I feel equipped to carry on with the discussion. First, I never used the term "in general" in my answer. You did! And then you wanted me to defend your made-up claim. I do see that my answer can be read that way and - from my professional experience - I do in fact maintain that less global state is better *in general*. My answer should be read as an answer to a specific question. You know: *all generalizations are wrong.* I'd happily improve my answer based on constructive criticism. I learned something from last night's exchange so I am somewhat grateful.