# How to temporarily change variable for included script in CMake without manual set before and after include?

Tags: cmake

I included a submodule in cmakefile and want to change a variable value temporarily in that submodule only. The best I can do is the following code, wondering if there is a more elegent way of doing it.

```
# dnn_lib
# Temporarily set USE_CUDA to OFF
set(OLD_USE_CUDA ${USE_CUDA})
set(USE_CUDA OFF)
include(dnn_lib)
include_directories(${DNN_LIB_INCLUDE_DIR})
set(USE_CUDA ${OLD_USE_CUDA})
```

Comment: This almost a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76570509/11107541 except that you're using `include` instead of `add_subdirectory`, so the parts of my answer there about directory scope of the subdirectory don't apply, since `include` does not create a new subdirectory scope and just uses the current one... I couldn't decide whether there way to close as duplicate, so I'm going to answer this.

Comment: on that note... I question the choice to `include` a submodule. If the submodule had its own CMake project, you'd typically `add_subdirectory`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)`, you can use [the `block` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/block.html) to create a new block scope where you redefine the variable or unset it and then call `include`, and then after the block scope is exited, the value from outside that scope is "restored". Pre-CMake 3.25, you can also achieve this by defining a function with the same body and calling it, but at that point, you don't really get any improvement over restoring the value manually.