Why does CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD defined in subdirectory in CMake affect the same variable in the parent CMake file?
I am working on a CMake project and I have encountered an issue where CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD defined in a subdirectory's CMakeLists.txt file seems to affect the same variable in the parent CMakeLists.txt file. I am confused about how the variable scoping works in CMake concerning parent and subdirectory relationships.
Here's a minimal example to illustrate the issue:
Parent CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(test_cmake LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} SHARED TestCMake.h TestCMake.cpp)

add_subdirectory(tests)

TestCMake.h
#include <optional>
#include <string>

class TestCMake
{
public:
        TestCMake() = default;

private:
       std::optional<std::string> m_string;
};

Subdirectory CMakeLists.txt (tests/CMakeLists.txt)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)

project(tests)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} "main.cpp")

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC test_cmake)

Output:
TestCMake.h:10:13: error: ‘optional’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
   10 |        std::optional<std::string> m_string;
      |             ^~~~~~~~
cmake_test/tests/../TestCMake.h:10:8: note: ‘std::optional’ is only available from C++17 onwards
   10 |        std::optional<std::string> m_string;
      |        ^~~
make[2]: *** [tests/CMakeFiles/tests.dir/build.make:76: tests/CMakeFiles/tests.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:126: tests/CMakeFiles/tests.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2

I expected the C++ standard in the parent directory to remain 17 as initially set, but it appears to change to 11 after the subdirectory script runs.
According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76570509/how-can-i-avoid-variable-inheritance-in-added-subdirectory-in-cmake, subdirectory will inherit variable in parent cmake, IMO, the variable in subdirectory is a local variable and will not affect parent variable. Why does this happen? Does CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD a global variable?

You could use target_compile_features instead and have CMake figure out the right C++ standard for you.

main.cpp includes TestCMake.h but is compiled with c++11 so won't work. Presumably TestCMake.cpp is compiling correctly in c++17 mode.
You can't set the c++ standard for header files, it only applies to cpp files.
